# Чтение из WinEvenlog golang

Tags: windows, golang

Подскажите, пожалуйста, рабочий пакет (желательно с примером) для чтения с помощью golang из winEventLog, пробовал использовать `gopkg.in/elastic/beats.v1/winlogbeat/eventlog`, но есть не стыковки исходного кода пакета с `github.com/elastic/beats/winlogbeat`

Comment: Можно попробовать через WMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно это сделать через WMI/WMQ, например так

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "log"

        "github.com/StackExchange/wmi"
    )

    type Win32_Process struct {
        ComputerName string
        Message      string
    }

    func main() {
        var dst []Win32_Process
        err := wmi.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'System'", &dst)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        for _, v := range dst {
            fmt.Println(v)
        }
    }
```

Полный список полей есть на сайте MS [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process), и к стати это можно делать удалённо.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, я пока ещё не видел библиотеки для чтения записей windows event log для golang

Но есть реализации парсинга EVTX файлов, думаю, вам это поможет:

- https://github.com/0xrawsec/golang-evtx
- https://github.com/elastic/beats/tree/master/winlogbeat/eventlog